# set many google markers from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a function that gets data in a json format. In order to display the markers in the google maps api I create a for loop to get the values from the json and set them in the marker variable. I try to use an if statement to intialize Marker only one time.

```
function setMarker() {
        $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/locator/car/gpspos/', function(car_pos) {

            for (i = 0; i < car_pos["json_data_list"].length; i++){

                if (i==0){
                    marker [i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                    });

                    userLat = car_pos["json_data_list"][i].latitude;
                    console.log(userLat);
                    userLon = car_pos["json_data_list"][i].longitude;
                    console.log(userLon);
                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
                    marker.setPosition(position);
                    map.setCenter(position);
                }

                else {

                    userLat = car_pos["json_data_list"][i].latitude;
                    console.log(userLat);
                    userLon = car_pos["json_data_list"][i].longitude;
                    console.log(userLon);
                    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
                    marker.setPosition(position);
                    map.setCenter(position);
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

I would be gratefull if sombody could help me with the for loop and if statement.

Comment: `i=0` is an assignment ; `i == 0` is a check

Comment: ok so if==0 I want to initialize the variable marker = []. Then I want to display all my markers in the google maps. marker = [marker1, marker2, marker3...] How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a check to initialize the marker, you have to make a Marker for each item you got in your JSON.

```js
function setMarker() {
  $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/locator/car/gpspos/', function(car_pos) {

    var marker = []; // don't forget the var keyword for local variables

    for (var i = 0; i < car_pos["json_data_list"].length; i++){ // same var keyword
        marker [i] = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });

        var userLat = car_pos["json_data_list"][i].latitude; // same var keyword
        console.log(userLat);
        var userLon = car_pos["json_data_list"][i].longitude; // same var keyword
        console.log(userLon);

        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLon);
        marker[i].setPosition(position); // marker[i] instead of marker
        map.setCenter(position); 
        // the map will be centered on the last marker added to the list.
    }
  });
}
```